# Hiding Label in Dygraph.js

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I am drawing a line at some certain point but what i want is that either i can hide the label for that particular line in the legend or i can change the value of that line in the legend

Note: The value at which the line is drawn and the value in the legend should be the same.Its one of my requirements

How is it possible ? Any help would be greatly appreciated .

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah i found it. value formatter was the thing i needed . I was able to change the value with the help of valueFormatter property in the dygraph option reference .